Number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{2}-px)$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ .

The number of ring homomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{2}-px) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(1_R)=1$, where $p$ is a prime number, is... ?

My attempt: We have $\phi (x^{2}-px)=0$ so that $\phi(x^{2})=p\phi(x)$. Now, let $\phi(x)=k$.
Then we have $k^{2}=pk$. So the only possible images of $\phi(x)$ are $0$ or $p$.
How to proceed from here? Is it enough to find the images of $x$ under $\phi$?

Yes, it is enough to find the image of $x$ as $$\phi(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j)= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \phi(x)^j.$$

Yes, it is enough to find the images of $x$ under $\phi$.
You can understand this using the universal property of the polynomial ring and quotient ring.
The universal property of polynomial ring $R[X]$ states that for all (commutative) ring homomorphism $R\to R'$ and map $X\to R'$, there is a unique homomorphism $R[X]\to R'$ whose restriction to $R$ and $X$ are the given ones.
The universal property of quotient ring states that all $R\to R'$ with $\operatorname{ker}$ containing $I$ factors like this:
$$R\to R/I\to R'$$
Put these facts together and it is clear that we only need to find $x\mapsto n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^2-pn=0$.

As $\phi(1)=1,$ we have $\phi (n)=\underbrace{\phi (1)+\dots +\phi(1)}_{\text{n-times}}=n\cdot 1=n.$
Thus $\Bbb Z$ is pointwise fixed, and it is sufficient to say what happens to $x$ under $\phi.$
As $\phi(x)=0$ or $p$ there are at most two homomorphisms.
Check whether you get well defined homomorphisms in each case.
Remember in $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-px)$ that $x^2=px,$ which reduces us to linear polynomials.

This proves that there are at most two homomorphism. One still needs to check that they actually define homomorphisms.
